# How to import types from cassandra driver in typescript?

Tags: typescript

The [Cassandra driver docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.0/features/datatypes/uuids/), show code like this:

```
const Uuid = require('cassandra-driver').types.Uuid;
const id = Uuid.random();
```

But when I do that in Visual Studio Code, it doesn't see `Uuid` as a class type.

[image]

I was trying to use ES6 style imports:

```
import cassandra from 'cassandra-driver'
```

How to you import that `Uuid` type so that typescript sees it correctly?

A type alias seems to work. Is that idiomatic? It seems a little verbose if I want to do it for multiple types.

```
type Uuid = cassandra.types.Uuid
```

Update: Actually, that doesn't work well. I can't call `Uuid.fromString(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are just taking the value from the module. You need the type as well. Also if you are using `require` you need to use `import` otherwise what you are getting is the `require` function from node which returns `any` and erases all the useful types.

```
import cassandraDriver = require('cassandra-driver');
type Uuid = cassandraDriver.types.Uuid;
const Uuid = cassandraDriver.types.Uuid;
const id = Uuid.random();

interface Test {
    id: Uuid
}
```

Comment: Okay, great. There is a `TimeUuid` type right next to the `Uuid` type. Is there a shortcut for importing multiple types, like if I wanted both `Uuid` and `TimeUuid` for example?

Comment: @RobN not that I know of unfortunately .. you can just use the full type I guess ..